# Java flatMap - whats the difference stream.of() and collection.stream()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

I'm trying to understand `flatMap`: `flatMap(x->stream.of(x) )` does not flat the stream and `flatMap(x->x.stream())` works and gives the desired result.
Can someone explain the difference between two?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class TestFlatMap{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList("a","b");
        List<String> l2 = Arrays.asList("c","d");

        Stream.of(l1, l2).flatMap((x)->Stream.of(x)).forEach((x)->System.out.println(x));

        Stream.of(l1, l2).flatMap((x)->x.stream()).forEach((x)->System.out.println(x));
    }

}
```

Output :

```
[a, b]
[c, d]
a
b
c
d
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing you had in mind was this:

```
Stream.of(l1, l2)
      // String[]::new isn't really needed in this simple example,
      // but would be in a more complex one...
      .flatMap((x)->Stream.of(x.toArray(String[]::new)))
      .forEach((x)->System.out.println(x));
```

Which would also yield a flattened stream of `a, b, c, d` as you expected. `Stream.of()` comes in two flavours:

- [`Stream.of(T)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T-) taking a single value as explained also by [Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36822905/521799)
- [`Stream.of(T...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-) taking an *array* (not a `List` as you expected)

Since, when passing a `List` to `Stream.of()`, the only applicable overload is the one taking a single value, you got a `Stream<List<String>>` rather than the expected `Stream<String>`

Answer (score 7):

`Stream.of(x)` produces a Stream of a single element - `x`. Therefore, `flatMap` returns a `Stream<List<String>>` instead of `Stream<String>`.

On the other hand, `x.stream()` where `x` is a `Collection<E>` returns a `Stream<E>` whose source are the elements of the `Collection`, so in your case it returns a `Stream<String>`, which allows `flatMap` to produce a `Stream<String>` containing all the `String`s in all the `List<String>`s of the source `Stream`.

You can see that in the Javadoc:

> `<T> Stream<T> java.util.stream.Stream.of(T t)`
>   Returns a sequential Stream **containing a single element**.

vs.

> `Stream<E> stream()`
>   Returns a sequential Stream **with this collection as its source**.